# Strange behaviour when using search view in android

Tags: android, listview, search, searchview

i've successfully implemented a searchView in a listView in android, but what i see now is something strange, i don't know if it's normal or just something i wrote wrong.

[image]

when some text is entered app opens this black layout with the text i'm searching, it's cool but i don't know how to handle with that...

[image]

anyone can help me?

thanks guys :)

Comment: what behavior are you looking for.some code would be nice

Comment: i don't want that black layout when i'm searching... cause was not expected to be there !